# Live Data in FireDac

Tags: delphi, firedac

Is it possible in FireDac get live data from database (SQL Server in my case) without updating DataSources like it was in Paradox. The closest things I could found was Live Data Window of FDTable, but information is very scanty and I don’t even sure that Live Data Window means that data is updated automatically. I need it for some obvious reasons. For example database sends some alert and user sees it without TTimer or constantly updating some specific DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I never used LiveDataWindows for any of my programs, but I Think, as you mentioned above, you should give `FDTable` a try.
Here is the Link on how to set it up correctly on MSSSL Server as well.

[Embarcadero docwiki](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Browsing_Tables_(FireDAC))

You can build a little trial app using the code from docwiki:

```
uses
  Windows;
...
// Set locale ID to German phone book collation
FDTable1.FormatOptions.SortLocale := MAKELCID(MAKELANGID (LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_GERMAN), SORT_DEFAULT);
// Use the the punctuation and other symbols case insensitive sorting
FDTable1.FormatOptions.SortOptions := [soNoSymbols];
FDTable1.IndexFieldNames := 'NAME';
FDTable1.TableName := 'CUSTOMERS';
FDTable1.Open;
```